# HAML/CoffeScript vs HTML/JavaScript for React on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I want to use React with Rails. I already know html/JS, Begineer at Rails and just finished some tutorials on official site on React. Now I want to lear to use React with Rails. I noticed that many tutorials are using haml + coffescript. After researching on those two I found that they make developing easier and code more readable. But some people say that they generate bad html and JavaScript.

Is haml + coffescript worth learning for using them with React on Rails.

One of the reasons why I am not sure whether to use or not hamls/coffescript is that official documentation for React is written for Javascript.

Answer (score 4):

"Some people say that they generate bad html and javascript". Keep in mind that *some people* will always say anything (which, by the way, is probably why your question got downvoted: you're inviting an opinions war, and the SO community hates those.)

The main considerations that come to mind are:

- How easy / hard will your learning curve be, with each technology stack?
- Are both tech stacks "compatible" with React? (Given the prevalence of React / Rails tutorials you've found that use Coffee, it looks like they are.)
- How familiar are you with Haml and Coffee? How familiar are you with pure Javascript? (I'd err on the side of the *more familiar environment* and learn things one at a time when possible.)
- How much **fun does it seem to be** to write code using each tech stack? (You'll learn faster and write better code if you love it.)

It sounds like you can't make a bad choice here, but if Haml or Coffee are new to you, I'd err on the side of the simpler technologies for now. You can always upgrade in a few weeks, right?

Good luck and hope you enjoy it!